# MVC3, CSS3 - cannot get styles picked up in a textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, css, razor

I have just seen a training video about CSS3 and it looked a great idea to put in these styles in my MVC application;

```
input.data:required {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.04);
}

input.data:focus {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border: 5px solid #ff5400;
}
```

So this will put in a background colour for required fields, and highlight the textbox that is in focus.
However these styles do not get picked up in my MVC form;

```
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: right">
                    Client Organisation Name<span class="error">*</span>
                </td>                    
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.clientContact.ContactName, 
                        new { autocomplete = "off", maxlength = "255", style = "text-transform: capitalize; width:400px;" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.clientContact.ContactName)
                </td>
            </tr>
```

When I inspected the textbox field, I saw the input element had a type of "text-box". So I changed input.data to input.text-box and input.text.
But this did not work either.
So what do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

`.data` is actually a class name applied on `textbox`. Define a css class name `data` on your textbox.

**Like this:**

```
<td>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.clientContact.ContactName, 
        new { autocomplete = "off", maxlength = "255", @class= "data", style = "text-transform: capitalize; width:400px;" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.clientContact.ContactName)
</td>
```

**Note the `@class= "data"` in the above code.**

## OR use another way mentioned below:

use `input[type=textbox]` instead of `input.text-box` or `input.data` in your css like this:

```
input[type=textbox]:required {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.04);
}

input[type=textbox]:focus {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border: 5px solid #ff5400;
}
```

Comment: I prefer the "OR" option - easier to implement. However the input[type=textbox]:required style does not work with this solution as there does not appear to be a "required" setting on the textbox. Also I used input[type="text"]:focus for this to work. So half a tick so far...